# Sonata ecommerce product list error

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I sucessfully installed the sonata ecommerce bundle into my project. But when I go into the product list from the admin dashboard I get the following error from doctrine.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT count(DISTINCT p0_.id)
 AS sclr0 FROM product__product p0_ LEFT JOIN product__product_category p1_ ON p0_.id = p1_.product_id LEFT JOIN classification__category c2_ ON p1_.category_id = c2_.id LEFT JOIN product__product_collection p3_ ON p0_.id = p3_.product_id LEFT JOIN classification__collection c4_ ON p3_.collection_id = c4_.id WHERE p0_.product_type IN ()':
```

I dont know whats going on as media bundle and categories seems to be working fine so far.

Comment: I know nothing of sonata but `WHERE p0_.product_type IN ()` doesn't seem right to me. Perhaps you need to add some product types somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple actually. I stumbled upon this problem as well.

Create a Product type (http://sonata-project.org/bundles/ecommerce/master/doc/reference/tutorials/create-product.html)
php app/console sonata:product:generate Bowl sonata.ecommerce_demo.product.bowl

import all resources

This being done, edit the src/Application/Sonata/ProductBundle/Entity/Bowl.php to make it inherits the Product class.

class Bowl extends Product
{

}

Note: don't forget to import sonata_product.yml(which isn't mentioned in the doccumentation). Add `- { resource: sonata/sonata_product.yml }` to your config.yml